# How to remove top tab from the screen in react native?

Tags: react-native, wix-react-native-navigation

I'm using wix react native navigation,I can navigate to a screen using

```
Navigation.events().registerAppLaunchedListener(() => {
Navigation.setRoot({
root: {
stack: {
  children: [{
    component: {
      name: 'myproject.AuthScreen',
      passProps: {
        text: 'stack with one child'
      }
    }
  }],
  options: {
    topBar: {
      title: {
        text: 'Welcome screen'
      }
    }
  }
}
}
})
});
```

But how to remove the top tab from that screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in the options :

```
topBar: {
   visible: false,
   drawBehind: true,
   animate: false,
},
```

Answer (score 0):

In the component where you want to hide or show you can add this static function

```
export default class Screen extends Component {
  static get options() {
    return {
      topBar: {
        title: {
          text: 'Screen',
        },
        visible: false,
        drawBehind: true,
        animate: false,
      },
    };
  }
}
```